# Ternary operator with multiple conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Hello I am trying to properly format ternary operator to be using multiple conditions in php:

```
$result = ($var !== 1 || $var !== 2) ? '' : 'default';
```

The problem is that in this format I always get not true even iv the $var is 1 or 2. With one condition for example `$var == 0` it is working fine. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Are you comparing against a string? Try `$var !== '1'` (with quotes) or `$var != 1`

Comment: If `$var` is equals to `1`, it's never equals to `2` and back. Don't you want `&&`?

Comment: Try  $result = ($var !== 1) ? ' ' : (($var !== 2) ? ' ' : 'default')

Comment: Oh, and FYI, that has nothing to do with the ternary operator itself. We'd get the same behaviour with an `if - else` statement (since this is more of a logic problem)

Comment: You could also use `$result = in_array($var, [1, 2]) ? 'default' : '';`. If you end up with any more conditions to check, I would recommend that rather than adding more `&&` or `||`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This statement will *always* be `true`:

```
($var !== 1 || $var !== 2)
```

Because `$var` can never simultaneously be both values, it will always *not* be at least one of the two values.  Which satisfies the `||` operator.

If you want to know whether `$var` is one of the two values:

```
($var === 1 || $var === 2)
```

If you want to know if `$var` is *neither* of the two values, you can negate the condition:

```
(!($var === 1 || $var === 2))
```

Or individually negate the operators in the condition and use `&&` instead of `||` (since all conditions need to be met to prove the negative, instead of just one condition to prove the positive):

```
($var !== 1 && $var !== 2)
```

Depending on readability and personal preference.

Comment: _"This statement will always be true: `($var !== 1 || $var !== 2)`"_. That's true even when there is no `$var` defined: [https://3v4l.org/kQHE0](https://3v4l.org/kQHE0) xD

Answer (score 2):

If $var is 0 , $result is "default" but 1 and 2 enter in condition, both are different from both and always enter.

```
$result = ($var !== 1 && $var !== 2) ? '' : 'default';
```